# noweb style weaving in org-babel

Tags: emacs, org-mode, literate-programming, org-babel

I'm using Emacs 23 with Org 7.8.04. My code structure is as follows:

```
#+TITLE: hello, world!

#+BEGIN_SRC python :tangle yes :noweb yes
<<go_function>>
if __name__ == "__main__":
    go()
#+END_SRC

Define =go_function= as follows.

#+name:go_function
#+BEGIN_SRC python
def go:
    print "hello, world!"
#+END_SRC
```

When I tried to *weave* documentation, the `<<go_function>>` in the first code chunk is exported to html too so that I have two html exports of `<<go_function>>`. I'd like the  `<<go_function>>` is exported as a link which points to the actual definition at the end of the document.How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing `:noweb yes` to `:noweb tangle`.  The manual is very helpful in cases like this (see https://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-Reference-Syntax.html).

Comment: What is the command within Emacs to access this page of the manual?